# Камера не синхронизирует время по NTP если ее переключить в порт NVR

Tags: ntp, видеонаблюдение

Камера видеонаблюдения G.Craftsman модель B3M5S отлично работает с видеорегистратором, когда подключена к нему через LAN. NTP от локального сервера работает без каких-либо проблем. Но если камеру переключить с коммутатора LAN на вход PoE видеорегистратора, то камера перестает синхронизировать время. Другие камеры, подключенные к этим портам синхронизируются нормально.
Как синхронизировать время в камере?